# Why spring boot .gradle project not support the external .jar files?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I have build gradle spring boot project with add external .jar with lib folder.but it was not building properly.

**gradle.build**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile group: 'rezg.rezos', name: 'rezg-data-publisher', version: '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

**This is the jar path of project folder,**

[image]

But project building time getting this error,

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find rezg.rezos:rezg-data-publisher:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.
  Required by:
      project :

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

**What are the best possible options to resolve this issue?**

Answer (score 1):

Your first dependency declaration already should add the jar to the class path.
You don't need the second dependency, which it is not able to resolve, as it will look for that in the repositories you defined, not in the filetree.

So, just this should do it:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```